# Web Scraper Returning Nothing

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

below is my code for a webscraper, the issue I'm having is that it's not returning anything. Does anyone know what's going on?

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.homedepot.ca']
    start_urls = ['https://www.homedepot.ca/search?q=Malibu%20wide%20plank%20french%20montara#!q=Malibu%20wide%20plank%20french%20montara']

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.cs('div.quote'):
            title = quote.css('acl-product-card__title::text').getall()
            price = quote.css('acl-product-card__price::text').getall()
            combined = (title.text + ' ' + price.text)
            print(combined)
```

Comment: `allowed_domains` only takes the domain, second of all you should show the output when you run the scraper

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not raising an exception? This shouldn't work:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for quote in response.cs('div.quote'):
```

It should be `response.css` instead of `response.cs`

Also, seems that your start url is down.
[image]

Maybe it doesn't accept requests from my country.

In case it opens to you, you should check the Selectors to see what each of them are returning, that will allow you to pinpoint where is the issue.

Comment: hi, would this work?
```
  def parse(self, response):

        title = response.css('acl-product-card__title::text').getall()
        price = response.css('acl-product-card__price::text').getall()
        combined = (title.text + ' ' + price.text)
        print(combined)
```

Comment: Assuming the page opens for you, the Selectors should work (if the CSS ref is right). However you shouldn't call `price.text` or `title.text`, since the `.getall()` method you used will return a list and not an object. `print(title, price)` would do the trick.